# Sequentially iterate list of asynchronous functions until at least one returns truthy value in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Given an array containing references to asynchronous functions (which return promises or simple values), I want to sequentially iterate over it resolving each element, until at least one of the elements resolves to the truthy value.

The idea came from this simple synchronous code:

```
var hasAccess = (user.isAdmin() || user.isManager() || entity.isOwnedBy(user));
```

The code above works for synchronous functions well, but will break for asynchronous ones. I'm looking for an asynchronous replacement of the code above.

I expect it to be called like this (in ES6 syntax for brevity):

```
atLeastOneTruthy([
  () => user.isAdmin(),        // Called first
  () => user.isManager(),      // Called second if first returned falsy value
  () => entity.isOwnedBy(user) // Called third if all previous returned falsy values
]).then(function (result) {
  // result === (true || false)
}).catch(function () {
  // Promise chain is rejected when at least one element in rejected
});
```

All the functions in the example above return either promises or simple values directly.

Is there an out-of-the box solution for this? I'm using Bluebird promises, however, I couldn't find anything suitable in it's API. I can't use e.g. `Promise.any()`, because it only checks for resolved promises and doesn't check returned values. I can't use `Promise.map()` either, because it will execute all functions, but I wan't them to be executed only when necessary (i.e. when previous element failed).

A node module recommendation would be great (I couldn't find one), however, a concept of how `atLeastOneTruthy()` could be coded would also be nice because I have some doubts about its implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a `then` handler can return a promise, you can just make a recursive solution.

```
function atLeastOneTruthy(arrayOfCallables) {
  // Keep a numeric index to avoid mutating the input array.
  // This implementation is not safe for item removal, but appending is OK.
  let nextCallableIndex = 0;
  // Start with a false value as a base case. Use a "named function expression"
  // to allow for recursion.
  return Promise.resolve(false).then(function innerHandler(returnValue) {
    if (returnValue) {
      // If truthy, return immediately. Nothing else is evaluated.
      return returnValue;
    } else if (nextCallableIndex < arrayOfCallables.length) {
      // If falsy, get the next iterable...
      let nextCallable = arrayOfCallables[nextCallableIndex++];
      // ...then call it and try again, regardless of whether nextCallable
      // returns a simple value or a promise.
      return Promise.resolve(nextCallable()).then(innerHandler);
    } else {
      // We're out of callables, and the last one returned a falsy value.
      // Return false. (You could also return returnValue to parallel ||.)
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

**See also:** [Named function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression). You could also refactor to use a simple nested function.

Comment: @zerkms The function expression `innerHandler` passes itself into a `then` expression. This isn't recursive in the sense that the function will appear on the stack multiple times, but it is recursive in the sense that its execution is self-referential.

Comment: Oh, indeed, that's what I overlooked.

Comment: A very elegant solution! I've just finished my own "recursive" implementation, but I like your solution better. Thanks for taking a time! ; )

Comment: Is this level of optimization really necessary? Why not just wrap every callable in in the array  with a promise that is rejected according to some condition. You can then use bluebirds .any() method with ease.

Comment: @etherealite One can imagine that one of the callables accesses a database, or makes an external API call, or smashes an antique vase containing the return value on a slip of paper. I agree that this may be overkill from a performance standpoint, but it also may make sense if trying to conserve a limited resource.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can invent a new Promise method like `Promise.any()` which takes an array of promises and resolves when either one of them resolves and rejects only if none resolves.

```js
var one = _ => new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(rej.bind(null,"boom"),1000)),
    two = _ => new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(rej.bind(null,"crash"),1500)),
  three = _ => new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(res.bind(null,"yay..!"),500));

Promise.prototype.constructor.any = function(proms){
  return proms.length ? proms[0].then(v => v, r => Promise.any(proms.slice(1)))
                      : Promise.reject("none resolved");
};

Promise.any([one(),two(),three()]).then(v => console.log("From promise.any with love",v), r => console.log(r));
Promise.all([one(),two(),three()]).then(v => console.log(v), r => console.log("From Promise.all with love",r));
```